# Use proxy with Tweepy

Tags: python, proxy, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I want to use proxy (with/without auth) with Twitter API via Tweepy in Python
Reading the documentation I tried something (I think really wrong) like this:

```py
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, proxy='1.2.3.4:1234')
```

But obviously didn't work

Comment: Actually, tweepy add proxy attribute in Tweepy.API new version and you can use proxy.
you can see doc for detail [Tweepy.API](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Tweepy doesn't seems to support proxy, you can change the ones on your system changing the `https_proxy` variable

On Linux:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://xxxx:8888"
```

On Windows:

```
set https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port
```

You can do it before launching the script or inside it, using [subprocess](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators) to run a command

Comment: I tried windows command and seems no error (with admin right). How can i check if everything's good?

Comment: Go to a website who can show you your IP/you position based on your IP and see if it's different from before

Comment: Cannot edit the comment, but what I meant is that you should check the ip that the CLI has, by looking on website that return your IP. You can do it by installing cURL or wget. Hope it worked :)

Comment: Thanks, now work, I only have to use subprocesso to run inside my code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue due to twitter ban in my country, all i did was to download a VPN application(Hide me VPN) and the code worked.